# How to modify a frametitle to add a logo?

Tags: beamer

Setting the frame title in beamer is quite complex. I found sources that proposed solutions that didn't work well. Basically, I want to override

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{default}[1][left]
```

(located in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`)

within my corporate sty file. I want to copy the default over and add a small minipage with my corporate logo, 2em of space, and then the frame title. I see exactly where to add the minipage but what I can't figure out is how to override the beamer template.

Apparently, there isn't a `\redef` function. I don't want to use `\setbeamertemplate` because I think `#1` is actually a calculated text height for the color box. I want to override or redefine the default function with my own. One less than ideal solution is to simply import the image into my frame title but I would really like to avoid doing that for every frame.

How can I override a `\defbeamertemplate*` function?

Comment: `#1` has nothing to do text height, this is just an option to switch between left and right aligned frame titles. `[left]` is used as default value. If you don't need right aligned frames, you can savly overwrite the template with `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{....}` and replace the `#1` in the definition with `left`.

Comment: Alternatively you could copy the complete definition to your sty file and replace the name of the template, e.g. `\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mycompany}[1][left]` and use `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[mycompany]`. This way you could even switch between left and right aligned frametitles.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up `\defbeamertemplate` in the manual, you'll see that right before it there is a description of `\addtobeamertemplate`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-duck}%
\hspace*{2em}}{}

\begin{frame}[t]{I am a frame with a pic in the title}
But why does it have to be a duck?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you want to vertically align the duck, you may do

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-duck}}}$%
\hspace*{2em}}{}

\begin{frame}[t]{I am a frame with a pic in the title}
But why does it have to be a duck?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you load `tikz`, you have many additional options. In particular, you could work with overlays etc. Moreover, you could load the `tikzmarmots` package and have a marmot in the title!

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, the only thing which can be improved is to add an `example-image-marmot` :) We should ask @Skillmon about adding such an image to duckuments :)

Comment: @samcarter Maybe with a crystal ball. ;-)

Comment: I did try to add text but it didn't work. When I placed text in the before option, it resulted in an error. when I placed text in the after option, it placed the text below the title bar, which makes sense. I didn't see anywhere in the definition a call to a hook for this function. I can get you the error but it appears to just be a definition issue. I got the error even with a text like "testing". Also, like with your example, the text gets placed outside of the bounding title box and it doesn't work well with multi-row frame titles. (Those were the bugs I mentioned before. )

Comment: @BenHolland If you append a concrete example of what you have tried to your question I will be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: So far, I have tried:
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{testing before}{testing after}
This resulted in "You can't use \perdepth" in horizontal mode. 
I tried \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{testing after}
and this worked but it put the "testing after" text in a line below the title header.
I tried putting this in the beamerthemeMyTheme.sty:
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]{
\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par
}
And that resulted in \insertframetitle not \def'ed.

So far the only thing that I managed to get working is:

Comment: \newcommand{\LogoFrameTitle}[1]{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.75in}%
\includegraphics[height=0.5in,width=0.5in,keepaspectratio]{myLogo}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-.75in}%
#1%
\end{minipage}%
}

where each \frametitle looks like:
\frametitle{\LogoFrameTitle{Frame Title}}

Which while it is a solution, isn't a very stable or robust solution.

Comment: I tried to use that solution with "berlin" style. But as soon, as I add "\usetheme{Berlin}", I get "! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ "
error

Comment: I've identified yet another problem. Adding the logo does not reduce the size of the box available for the title. Try to duplicate the text in the title of the frame in the answer. You'll see that the text escapes outside the slide.

Comment: @wzab You could ask a new question for this. (Or just look up what `\addtobeamertemplate` does.) It is a bit cumbersome to get all the comments but no question that shows the actual code that is being used. A real question has a real MWE, i.e. a code that one can base an answer on, and such a real question will most likely get a real answer.